# Sparse Mixed Model with lme4 or other package

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, lme4, mixed-models

I use mixed models on a large file (500000 rows).
My model formula looks like this:
`Y ~ 0 + num1:factor1 + num1:factor2 + num2:factor3 + factor4 + (0 + num3|subject) +  (0 + num4|subject) + (1|subject)`,
where `num` - numeric variables; `factor` - categorical variables/factors.

Since **categorical variables have many unique levels**, the fixed effects matrix is ​​**very sparse** (sparsity ~0.9).
Fitting such a matrix if it is handle as dense requires a lot of time and RAM.

I had the same problem with linear regression.
My dense matrix was `20GB`, but when I converted it to sparse it became only `35 MB`.
So, I refused to use `lm` function and instead it used two another functions:

1. `sparse.model.matrix` (to create a sparse model/design matrix) and
2. `MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse` (to fit a sparse matrix and calculate coefficients).

Can I apply a similar approach to mixed models?
What functions / packages can I use to implement this?

That is, my main question is whether **it is possible to implement mixed models with sparse matrices**?
What functions should I use to create `X` and `Z` sparse model matrices?
Then, which function should I use for fitting the model with sparse matrices to get coefficients?

I would be very-very grateful for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As of version 1.0.2.1 on CRAN, `glmmTMB` has a `sparseX` argument:

> sparseX: a named logical vector containing (possibly) elements named
> "cond", "zi", "disp" to indicate whether fixed-effect model
> matrices for particular model components should be generated
> as sparse matrices, e.g. ‘c(cond=TRUE)’. Default is all
> ‘FALSE’

You would probably want `glmmTMB([formula], [data], sparseX=c(cond=TRUE))` (`glmmTMB` uses `family="gaussian"` by default).

`glmmTMB` is not quite as fast for linear mixed models as `lme4` is: I don't know what your mileage will be (but will be interested to here). There is also some discussion [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/467#issuecomment-706463448) about how to hack the equivalent of sparse model matrices in `lme4` (by letting the many-level factor be a random effect with a large fixed variance).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try `glmmTMB` today. QQ - I have looked at the source code of `lme4` and on line 727 of `modular.R` it says that the `sparseX` matrix has not been implemented yet, but do you plan to implement it in the future? Also, maybe you know, is it possible to use `ASReml` package for the implementation of sparse Mixed Models?

Comment: `sparseX` has been on the lme4 wish list for a *loong* time, I wouldn't hold my breath unless someone volunteers ... I have no idea about `ASReml`'s capabilities ... but [this](https://asreml.kb.vsni.co.uk/knowledge-base/asreml-object/) makes it seem likely ...